# Recebendo emails 2x do formulario

Tags: php

Olá, montei um formulario na minha pagina e para carregar tudo na mesma pagina coloquei a action=#contato (seção do formulario)

Mesmo clicando apenas 1x no botão ENVIAR, recebo 2 emails identicos.

Segue o `contato.php` que uso um `include` na mesma pagina inicial:

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
//pega as variaveis por POST
$nome     = $_GET["nome"];
$email    = $_GET["email"];
$fone     = $_GET["fone"];
$assunto  = $_GET["assunto"];
$mensagem   = $_GET["mensagem"];

global $email; //função para validar a variável $email no script todo

$data      = date("d/m/y");                     //função para pegar a data de envio do e-mail
$hora      = date("H:i");                       //para pegar a hora com a função date

//aqui envia o e-mail para você
mail ("contato@contato.com", //email aonde o php vai enviar os dados do form
      "$assunto",
      "Nome: $nome\nData: $data\nHora: $hora\nE-mail: $email\nTelefone: $fone\n\nMensagem: $mensagem",
      "From: $email"
     );

//aqui são as configurações para enviar o e-mail para o visitante
$site   = "contato@contato.com"; //o e-mail que aparecerá na caixa postal do visitante
$titulo = "Contato";    //titulo da mensagem enviada para o visitante
$msg    = "$nome, Seu e-mail foi recebido!\nObrigado por entrar em contato conosco, em breve entraremos em contato!";

//aqui envia o e-mail de auto-resposta para o visitante
mail("$email",
     "$titulo",
     "$msg",
     "From: $site"
    );
}
```

?>

Na pagina principal está mais ou menos assim

```
<? include "contato.php";?>
<form action="#contato">
</form>
```

E no final do formulário tenho outra parte em php para mostrar a msg de envio com sucesso

```
<?  
    if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        echo "<p>Sua mensagem foi entregue com sucesso!<br>";
        echo "Em até 48hrs você receberá um contato nosso. Obrigado!</p>";
    }
?>
```

Quando eu clico em enviar ele envia um e-mail e quando carrega a pagina de novo ele envia outro email ?

Existe alguma forma de eu cancelar o primeiro ou segundo envio?

Comment: Já tentou printar a variável $email antes e depois da chamada ao global $email para ver se essa variável altera?

Comment: Explica melhor esse `quando carrega a pagina de novo ele envia outro email`, vc está dizendo `refresh`?

Comment: se for refresh ele sempre vai enviar de novo pois na url tem os parâmetros necessários para envio e vc está usando `if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){`

Comment: Como é seu formulario?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você envia um e-mail e continua na mesma pagina, "dando um F5", o formulário sempre vai enviar de novo, pois os dados enviados por POST ficam armazenados, (Pode pegar como exemplo enviar algo por GET e atualizar a pagina. A URL se mantem.) o que você tem que fazer, é que quando o formulário for enviado, você usa um `window.location.href = "https://www.suaurl.com"` ou um `header("Location: https://www.suaurl.com");` e então não vai mais ocorrer o problema.

Answer (score 0):

> No seu código eu vejo 2 possibilidades de o email ser enviado 2 ou mais vezes.

- **2 vezes** se o email digitado no input do formulário for igual ao `email aonde o php vai enviar os dados do form`
- **2 ou mais vezes** se ficar dando refresh na página ou clicar repetidamente no botão ENVIAR.

Para contornar esse problema:

Crie uma `$_SESSION['me']` assim que o email for enviado com o valor do `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

> A variável $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] conterá os parâmetros passados em uma URL. Esses parâmetros são todos os caracteres existentes na url após o ponto de interrogação (?)

Atribua às variáveis `$string` e `$session`, respectivamente os valores `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` e `$_SESSION['me']`

Finalmente compare esses dois valores e se forem diferentes envia o email

```
if ($string!=$session){
 //envia email
```

**página contato.php**

```
//Inicia uma nova sessão
session_start(); 

$string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$session = $_SESSION['me'];

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

if ($string!=$session){

    if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        //pega as variaveis por POST
        $nome     = $_GET["nome"];
        $email    = $_GET["email"];
        $fone     = $_GET["fone"];
        $assunto  = $_GET["assunto"];
        $mensagem   = $_GET["mensagem"];

        global $email; //função para validar a variável $email no script todo

        $data      = date("d/m/y");                     //função para pegar a data de envio do e-mail
        $hora      = date("H:i");                       //para pegar a hora com a função date

        //aqui envia o e-mail para você


        mail ("nome@dominio.com", //email aonde o php vai enviar os dados do form
              "$assunto",
              "Nome: $nome\nData: $data\nHora: $hora\nE-mail: $email\nTelefone: $fone\n\nMensagem: $mensagem",
              "From: $email"
             );

        //aqui são as configurações para enviar o e-mail para o visitante
        $site   = "contato@contato.com"; //o e-mail que aparecerá na caixa postal do visitante
        $titulo = "Contato";    //titulo da mensagem enviada para o visitante
        $msg    = "$nome, Seu e-mail foi recebido!\nObrigado por entrar em contato conosco, em breve entraremos em contato!";

        //aqui envia o e-mail de auto-resposta para o visitante
        mail("$email",
             "$titulo",
             "$msg",
             "From: $site"
            ); 

        $_SESSION['me']=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 

    }

}
```

**Formulário**

```
   <form action="#contato">
    .......

<?  
    if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        echo "<p>Sua mensagem foi entregue com sucesso!<br>";
        echo "Em até 48hrs você receberá um contato nosso. Obrigado!</p>";
    }
?>
```

Caso se deseje disponibilizar novo envio de email basta colocar `echo "<a href=\"principal.php\">Enviar outro email</a>";` no código acima.

```
<?  
    if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        echo "<p>Sua mensagem foi entregue com sucesso!<br>";
        echo "Em até 48hrs você receberá um contato nosso. Obrigado!</p>";

        echo "<a href=\"principal.php\">Enviar outro email</a>";
    }
?>
```

> OBS: o metodo Get tem um tamanho limitado , se a informação for muito grande corre o risco de haver perda de dados.

```
Internet Explorer: 2.083 caracteres
Firefox: 65.536 caracteres
Safari: 80.000 caracteres
Opera: 190.000 caracteres
```

[comprimento máximo da URL IE](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/208427/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer)